# IDQ input parameter file error in windows

Tags: batch-file, informatica, informatica-powercenter, data-quality

In IDQ process, I have generated a workflow parameter in server location.

When I am trying to call with the batch script the parameter file with different source file names facing an error which shows the parameter file is not found.

It was not able to pick the diff file names with multiple input parameter's.

Comment: You should take the [tour] (again), read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

In IDQ there is option in values where the default value must be set for the port where the name is specified.

It might be taking the name mentioned there and giving error for the parameter value.